# in flexbox how to push next row element close to right top element of previous row, without negative margins?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three elements wrapped in flex container, by two in a row:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem-1">a</div>
  <div class="elem-2">b</div>
  <div class="elem-3">c</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to push last row element close right top element, without editing html code and using negative margins ?

[image]

this dummy css code demonstrates what I want to get, but without negative margins

```
.container {
    display:flex;
  width:205px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-items:flex-start;
}
.elem-1 {
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:100px;

}

.elem-2 {
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:50px;
}

.elem-3 {
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:102px; // push element to the right
  margin-top:-50px;  // push to the top
}
```

with this negative margin on `elem-3` I am pushing it to last top element, is there a way to avoid it and still use flexbox, not floats ?

result I try to get:

[image]

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j51o1cup/

Comment: this feels like 'masonry' with flexbox, so an example like https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/eAqzk may be helpful to figure out for your use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this can't be done using Flexbox alone and with dynamic content.

If you can set a height on the `container`, then here is a trick, using a pseudo element to push the `elem-2` and `elem-3` to a new column

By making the pseudo to be ordered between `elem-1` and `elem-2`, we can tell it to be full height. When done like that, it will create its own column, keeping the `elem-1` to the left and the `elem-2` and `elem-3` to the right

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 205px;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  order: 1;
}

.elem-1 {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

.elem-2 {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  order: 2;
}

.elem-3 {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem-1">a</div>
  <div class="elem-2">b</div>
  <div class="elem-3">c</div>
</div>
```