# Forcing a wrap on column flex box layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Please see the example attached.

i need the following:

- have a column layout. `flex-direction:column;`
- have a wrap break-point after child 2.
- all childs must be directly descendant of parent container.

Currently i can achieve this by specifying explicit height to the container. for example: `height:100px`.

however, i don't want to do this. i want the second child take as height as it needs to have (by the content), and the third child to follow on the second column.

thanks.

```css
.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.child {padding: 0.5em;background: rgba(0,0,255,0.15);}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
 <div class="child one">Child One</div>
 <div class="child two">Child Two</div>
 <div class="child three">Child Three</div>
  <div class="child four">Child Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't unless you set a fixed height on the flex container. With a fixed height you could do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45827123/2827823

Comment: Firefox can do this `.child.two {
  page-break-after: always; /* CSS 2.1 syntax */
  break-after: always; /* New syntax */
}`

Comment: page-break-after is not relevant to flexbox, am i correct? if i am wrong, can you demonstrate with code?

Comment: Check last sample in this answer, and use Firefox: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29733127